# AngularJS - app architecture

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building my first AngularJS app.

I am wanting to dynamically change the page title upon route change, so I first tried structuring my app as:

```
<html ng-app>
```

I'm wanting to have a page-level controller, then have sub-controllers below that.

So, I started by:

```
var app = angular.module("squareUpYourSavings", ["page1", "page2", "..."]);

app.controller('GlobalController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function GlobalController($scope, $rootScope) {

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
        $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;
    });

    $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function (event, nextLocation, currentLocation) {
            console.log('nextLocation :: ' + nextLocation);
            console.log('currentLocation :: ' + currentLocation);
        });
```

But this doesn't work. (not sure why)   I have a nav that points to directory-level controllers and the ng-view DOES work, but the <title> doesn't change.  Nor does the $locationChange listener fire at all.  It's as if this top-level Controller isn't even being heard at all.

So, then I changed the <html> element to specify the top-level controller:

```
<html id="ng-app" ng-controller="GlobalController">
```

This does now work, but the route seems to be firing twice.  Initial page load shows this:

```
nextLocation :: location.html#/
currentLocation :: location.html#/
```

When I then go to a route, it correctly fires the before & after, but then double-fires when I get there:

```
nextLocation :: location.html#savings-video         // expected
currentLocation :: location.html#/                  // expected
nextLocation :: location.html#/savings-video/       // not expected
currentLocation :: location.html#savings-video      // not expected
```

Is this expected behavior?  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For *global* stuff that is related to the whole app and not a certain module - like the title, I suggest you put the logic in the *main controller*: the `run` module method :

```
var app = angular.module("squareUpYourSavings", ["page1", "page2", "..."]);
app.run(function($rootScope) {
     $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
         $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;
     });
});
```

Oh, and you should leave your router to decide which controller is in "*control*":

```
<html ng-app>
```